# Rewriting nginx's try_files rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a question about nginx's rewrite rules.

My code is as follows

```
  location ~* \.(jpg)$ {
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header Content-Type image/jpeg;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Capture1 $1;
    add_header Capture2 $2;
    add_header X-uri "$uri";
    try_files $uri @find_file;
    root /data;
  }
  location @find_file {
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header Content-Type image/jpeg;
    expires 30d;

    rewrite ^/(.*(\w)(\w)(\w))\.jpg$ /d/$4/$3/$2/$1.jpg break;
  }
```

But there may be no files in rewrite

So, I want to show php

```
  try_files $uri @find_file /test.php?uri=$uri;
```

However, this will cause php to run even if there is a file in @find_file.

I want to reduce the frequency of running php.

What should I do?

(When you run php, php puts the file in that location.@find_file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to replace the `rewrite` statement with a `try_files` term and use the captures from the `location` statement.

For example:

```
root /data;

location ~* ^/(.*(\w)(\w)(\w))\.jpg$
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header Content-Type image/jpeg;
    expires 30d;

    try_files $uri /d/$4/$3/$2/$1.jpg /test.php?uri=$uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.